# Can start-stop-daemon use environmental variables?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, daemon, pid

I need to daemonize a Windows app running in Wine, and create a pid in `/var/run`. Since it requires an X11 session to run, I need to make sure the $DISPLAY variable is set in the running user's environment.

Assuming I already have a X11 session running, with a given display, here's what the start-stop-daemon line looks like in my `/etc/init.d` script:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/wine-app.pid -m -c myuser -g mygroup -k 002 --exec /home/myuser/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/wine-app.exe
```

Unfortunately, my version of start-stop-daemon on Ubuntu 8.04 doesn't have the `-e` option to set environmental variables. I gather that you could simply set $DISPLAY before the command, like so:

```
VAR1="Value" start-stop-daemon ...
```

But it doesn't work. Since I'm using the `-c {user}` option to run as a specific user, I'm guessing there's an environment switch and VAR1 is lost. I've tried exporting DISPLAY from the running user's `.profile` and/or `.bashrc` but it doesn't work either.

Is there another way to do this? Is this even possible? Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a shell script to set the variable and then run wine.

Comment: Haven't had the chance to put this in to practice, but I wrote the script and it seems like the best way to go. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 23):

You can use `env` to modify the environment:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/wine-app.pid -m -c myuser -g mygroup -k 002 --exec /usr/bin/env VAR1="Value" /home/myuser/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/wine-app.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Gentoo version](https://docs.sysrq.in/start-stop-daemon#e) of start-stop-daemon utility has an `-e`/`--env` option:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/wine-app.pid -m \
    -c myuser -g mygroup -k 002 -e VAR1="Value" -e VAR2="Other value" \
    --exec /home/myuser/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/wine-app.exe
```

Comment: Welcome! This answer is OK for general reference, but the OP mentions that "my version of start-stop-daemon on Ubuntu 8.04 doesn't have the -e option"